# HDR Image Rendered circular

Tags: rendering, hdri

[image]I just loaded in a HDR image using the node editor using the Environment Text and it renders well the mountains in the distance look good but then the bottom of the image is twisted in a circular pattern all smeared together. My image is 3000X1970 and I am using the default camera. I am using cycles render. I have looked at every setting I can think of to correct this but nothing. 
I did try to find the answers online before I asked here but I guess I am not typing in the right search questions.

Is my image the wrong size? I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks 
Blender  2.79

Here is the image that was requested. This in another image I downloaded which is a Panoramic HDR and this was even worse than my first image. Thanks again.

Comment: Some spherical images have naturally poorer quality at the poles where they get more warped simply because of limitations on the capturing method. It may be unrelated to Blender settings. Also 3000x1970 for a spherical image is admittedly poor

Comment: This image looks nothing like others I have seen even the distant mountains are somewhat distorted. What is the best size HDR for Blender? This one is just not working well. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that exemplify the issue and  also show  your current  mapping settings and the original HDR

Comment: "*What is the best size HDR for Blender?*" There is no "best size". Smaller images consume less memory, larger ones have better quality, choose your balance wisely. There are environments maps that go above 16000px wide

Comment: Try choosing projection method; open Node editor, switch it to World nodes and in the Image Texture node choose Equirectangular or Mirror Ball projection depending on your image (it's usually written in description for it)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Zak already tried these options. The Mirror Ball is even worse.I will try some different HDR images. I am not sure what  i am doing wrong.

Comment: The fact that the image is curved in the viewport suggest to me that this is not a properly formed equirectangular image nor a mirror ball.  Try another image from https://cloud.blender.org/p/hdri/

Comment: Thanks Mike for the suggestion. I was thinking the same thing last night but could not find the right kind of HDR images. I did check out the link you sent but was not interested in signing up on another site. I did find this site https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/ which has plenty of free HDR images with no sign up. And yes the problem with solved using the correct HDR images. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.